# Lio iSCSI target on OpenSUSE?

Tags: iscsi, opensuse

I want to use an iSCSI targeting framework that supports SCSI-3 and [VAAI](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1021976) for use as an iSCSI SAN cluster across 2 servers.

As far as i'm aware I can use either Lio (http://linux-iscsi.org/wiki/Main_Page) or QuadStor (http://www.quadstor.com/). Quadstor isn't as mature as LIO hence my bias towards it.

I have 2 servers built on openSUSE 12.3 (of course this can be changed) for the moment and am having a hell of a problem finding out how to use LIO.

LIO was integrated into the Linux Kernel at v2.6.38 in January 2011 and is now used as the default SCSI framework in Linux. *That's all fine, but how the hell do I use it?*

According to their docs all I have to do is install `targetcli` from their repo for openSUSE: http://linux-iscsi.org/wiki/Target

Did that, nada.

What's the best OS or best way to get about using LIO that supports VAAI preferably through kernel integration?

Comment: @sysadmin1138 - Do you have experience with this (based off your earlier blog post on openSUSE 11.3)

Comment: Nope. All of my experience with it was before kernel integration, and I'm no longer working with it day to day. A lot has changed in the years since that blog-post.

Comment: Finally got it working with all the nice VAAI features tested and working great on vSphere 5 - writing a guide on it currently, will post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are 4 commands that need to be implemented in target for VAAI support, namely:

1. WriteSame
2. UNMAP
3. ComareAndWrite(ATS)
4. EXtendedCOPY(XCOPY)

On the LIO side you need to set emulate_3pc(Xcopy),emulate_tpu(UNMAP) and emulate_caw(ATS), so you will get VAAI supported status for the LIO target on the esxi side.

```
targetcli> /backstore/fileio/disk1>set attributes emulate_3pc=1,emultate_tpu=1,emulate_caw=1
```

Refer [linux-iscsi.org/wiki/Targetcli](http://linux-iscsi.org/wiki/Targetcli)   for details.